# How add server-side git hooks in Assembla?

Tags: git, githooks, assembla

How can i add server-side hooks in Assembla for all users this repository? If i add in .git/hooks it's be only for my local repository or i don't understand something?

I need hooks for check and edit commit messages for all users of repository.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings tab of your git repo on the Assembla site, you should see "server side hooks" - this is where you can install and configure server side hooks.

There is nothing to be done locally.